# Code Check to ensure code matches the math? [optimization problem, code works just want to ensure it lines up with the math]

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, minimize

I thought of posting this on code check, but I'm not looking to improve the code, I'm rather looking for someone to check my code is doing what I want it to be doing (i.e. I've set it up correctly). It works, but I want to ensure the output is correct.

Code is posted at bottom, here I will discuss what I am attempting to do.

I am attempting to minimize 2 variables globally. These 2 variables can be used to calculate A, B, and C (the equations are irrelevant, all that matters is these 2 variables can be used to calculate these 3 numbers).

```
A=(-k[0]*k[1]+np.sqrt(k[0])*np.sqrt(k[1])*np.sqrt(k[0]*k[1]+8*io*(1+2*k[1])))/(4+8*k[1])
B=(k[1]*(k[0]*k[1]+io*(4+8*k[1])-np.sqrt(k[0])*np.sqrt(k[1])*np.sqrt((8*io)+(16*io*k[1])+(k[0]*k[1]))))/(2*(1+2*k[1])**2)
C=(k[0]*k[1]+io*(4+8*k[1])-np.sqrt(k[0])*np.sqrt(k[1])*np.sqrt((8*io)+(16*io*k[1])+(k[0]*k[1])))/(4*(1+2*k[1])**2)
```

A, B, and C can then be combined with theoretical data that I have, to provide a theoretical model.

```
model=fractionA*intensityA+fractionB*intensityB+fractionC*intensityC
```

Where intensityA, intensityB, and intensity3 is theoretical data that are given

This model is then compared to experimental data. And a minimization is done to give the 2 variable values, that can generate A,B, and C values for each dataset to match the experimental data.

You will note outside of the 2 variables, A,B, and C are also dependent on io. This is a given constant. Every constant of io, will have an associated array of theoretical and experimental data (intensityA, intensityB, intensityC, and experimental_data).

In other words, data format would be:

```
io=[10.0,5.0,2.5]
intensityA=[[theoretical data from 10.0],[theoretical data from 5.0],[theoretical data from 2.5]]
#same would be true for intensityB and intensityC
experimental_data=[[experimental data from 10.0],[experimental data from 5.0],[experimental data from 2.5]]
```

Each dataset, will have the same value for A, B, and C. This is why I reshape and extend A, B, and C for each dataset.

I won't post the get_data() code here because it's just going through all the folders and organizing all the data. But the format would be like this:

```
def get_data():
    return np.random.rand(3,1),np.random.rand(30,200),np.random.rand(30,200),np.random.rand(30,200),np.random.rand(30,200)
```

One final tidbit, not all my data are the same size (I store each intensity in one list of lists across all experiments). Within a single io value they are the same size, but not across different io values. So I resized them

```
(np.array(list(itertools.zip_longest(*data_list,fillvalue=0))).T)
```

I presume filling the missing data with zeros is fine and shouldn't influence the fitting. Since zero values of all 3 intensities would give a model with a value of 0, and this would also apply to the experimental data too (the theoretical and experimental are always the same size to each other). So the experimental would be zero and the chi^2 would be zero, so this should not influence minimization.

So for example, for io=5.0, Aintensity might be 100, but for io=10.0 Aintensity will be 200. So by running the above code in my getdata(), Aintensity will be filled with zeros until it is 200.

My final shapes for my actual data set is: `(30,),(30,2221),(30,),(30,2221),(30,),(30,2221),(30,),(30,2221)` for io,intensityA,intensityB,intensityC,experimental_intensity respecitvely.

If anything is unclear, please let me know!

The code:

```
def generate_model(fractionA,fractionB,fractionC,intensityA,intensityB,intensityC):
    model=fractionA*intensityA+fractionB*intensityB+fractionC*intensityC
    return model

def k_k1(k,io,intensityA,intensityB,intensityC,experimental_data):
    A=(-k[0]*k[1]+np.sqrt(k[0])*np.sqrt(k[1])*np.sqrt(k[0]*k[1]+8*io*(1+2*k[1])))/(4+8*k[1])
    B=(k[1]*(k[0]*k[1]+io*(4+8*k[1])-np.sqrt(k[0])*np.sqrt(k[1])*np.sqrt((8*io)+(16*io*k[1])+(k[0]*k[1]))))/(2*(1+2*k[1])**2)
    C=(k[0]*k[1]+io*(4+8*k[1])-np.sqrt(k[0])*np.sqrt(k[1])*np.sqrt((8*io)+(16*io*k[1])+(k[0]*k[1])))/(4*(1+2*k[1])**2)
    fractionA=np.tile(((np.array([A/io])).reshape((len(intensityA),1))),(len(intensityA[0])))
    fractionB=np.tile(((np.array([B/io])).reshape((len(intensityA),1))),(len(intensityB[0])))
    fractionC=np.tile(((np.array([C/io])).reshape((len(intensityA),1))),(len(intensityC[0])))
    model=generate_model(fractionA,fractionB,fractionC,intensityA,intensityB,intensityC)
    return np.sum((model-experimental_data)**2) 

def optimize_k():
    io,intensityA,intensityB,intensityC,experimental_intensity=get_data()
    bnds = [(0.0, np.inf), (0.0, np.inf)] 
    xinit = np.array([1000.0, 0.01]) 
    solution=minimize(k_k1,args=(io,intensityA,intensityB,intensityC,experimental_intensity), x0=xinit, bounds=bnds)    
    print(solution)

optimize_k()
```

Comment: A, b, c can be greatly simplified (I've done this locally). But you need to supply get_data for this to be reproducible.

Comment: but what I'm asking is have I set up the code properly? Like is it minimizing what I want it to be minimizing?